# Disable desktop.ini files on external drives

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, desktop.ini

I've read through the solutions discussing disabling desktop.ini files globally, but I'd just like to disable the creation of desktop.ini files on my local machine.  My work policy is to not allow files to be moved to external drives, which means that I get a notification every time I do anything with an external drive complaining that it couldn't write the desktop.ini file.

Comment: Any solution would require elevated permissions.

Comment: What are you doing that makes the computer want to write a `desktop.ini` file to an external drive? Have you relocated system folders to the drive? Assigned a custom icon to a folder? Added comments? Ordinary file system folders don't have a `desktop.ini` file...

Comment: I do have access to elevated permissions @Ramhound - the company grants automatic 1-hour admin sessions on request.

Comment: @KeithMiller I don't know why it wants to write those files, but I do know it does.  I haven't copied any folders there.  I copied some images from the drive to my desktop temporarily, but it was doing this beforehand as well.

Comment: Search the drive concerned like this in a command prompt `dir D:\desktop.ini /a /s`  What does it find?

Answer (score 0):

### Troubleshooting posted as answer for the sake of code formatting

Try copying each of the blocks below, pasting into a **PowerShell** console window, and executing (press `Enter`). Then scan the output for any paths that reference an external drive.

### HKCU...\User Shell Folders

```
gp 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'
```

### HKLM...\User Shell Folders

```
gp 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders'
```

### Known Folders ( Copy/paste entire block )

```
( gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\*' ).Name | %{[PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name' = $_
        'Path' = & { Try {  ( New-Object -com shell.application ).NameSpace("shell:$_").self.path } Catch { '<No Path>' } }
}} | ft -AutoSize
```